# How to manage onBlur events for composite input components in react

Tags: events, reactjs, onblur

I am writing a React component (v0.14.7+) that needs to call an onBlur callback (passed in via props) when the cursor leaves the component (via tab, mouse click or touch event).

The challenge is that this component has two input tags.  If the onBlur happens with the first I should not call the onBlur handler if the element gaining focus is the second input tag.  In other words I should only fire onBlur if the focus as left *BOTH* of the input elements.

I am looking for a clean solution to this problem that works cross-browser and ideally using just the React api/synthetic events.  I.e. without looking at the native event unless I really have to.  How should I do this?

Note that the onFocus event fires after the onBlur event so I can't do this by just keeping track of which field has focus.  Also the document.activeElement at the time the onBlur event fires seems to return the document object and *not* the active element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use timeout to postpone change of `hasFocus` (let's say) for a while. If there is another attempt to update `hasFocus`, clear pending scheduled `setState` attempt. Do not forget to clear timeout when unmounting component

See working example. Watch console, you won't get "true" and "false" printed when focusing from first <---> seconds input.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/38136/

Comment: I tried that, but I don't have the React event anymore.. (it's all nulled out by the time the timeout fires).  I assume this is due to React pooling/recycling events.  I want to pass the event to the onBlur handler.  SO my question is how do I create a React synthetic event object?

Comment: You are right about event handling in React. You can persist event (prevent it from being recycled by React). See note in Event polling section https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling. Look for `event.persist()` See updated fiddle where I log the input which received `blur` event as last